# How to connect WiFi module and Miсrocontroller via MII interface

Tags: pcb, ethernet, wifi, lpc

```
WiFi module:     WIZ610WI
Microcontroller: LPC1788
Purpose:         Connect it via MII on PCB
```

I have the following scheme:
[image: MAC-to-MAC via MII scheme]

1. Do I need a signal delay on TX_CLK?
2. On what line and what the value of the resistor to set?
3. Are there guidelines for the design of such boards?

The image from:
[enter link description here](https://www2.smsc.com/mkt/web_lancheck.nsf/2f473f9215f487db852571b50046a891/6647cebf43d94b72852572b300443d47/$FILE/Schematic%20Design%20Guideline,%20MAC-to-MAC%20MII%20Interface.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In "Errata sheet LPC1788":

```
3.4  ETHERNET.1: In Ethernet MII mode, the transmit data TXD3:0 and 
transmit enable TX_EN incorrectly reference RX_CLK in data 
transmission

Problem:
In MII mode, the transmit data TXD3:0 and transmit enable TX_EN should reference the 
TX_CLK from the Ethernet PHY. However, due to a configuration error in the chip, the 
transmit data TXD3:0 and transmit enable TX_EN reference RX_CLK in data 
transmission. The consequence of this error is that a small percentage of packets cannot 
be received by the PHY. 

Work-around:
This will be fixed with the next silicon release. 

Note: There is no issue in RMII mode operation.
```

If I gather the scheme, will it work normal?